# launchd script never runs again after sleep

Tags: mac, launchd

The script specified in my launchd configuration works correctly (runs every 10 seconds) so long as my computer does not go to sleep. Once it does, I have to reload the launchd configuration. Here is my config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.maxwell.break</string>

    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>

    <key>Program</key> 
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>osascript</string>
      <string>/Users/maxwell/Google Drive/Dev/Launchd/break.scpt</string>
    </array>

  </dict>
</plist>
```

I thought the `KeepAlive` key might solve it, but it does not. The Applescript it runs just does the following:

```
display dialog "Break"
delay 10
```